# How to Optimize multiple if-else statements AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop, flash-cc

So I have my function `characterBooleanFunction` which holds over 30 if-else statements. When I run Scout to check performance it points right to this function which is also ran by a ENTER_FRAME event. Scout is showing me that the `gotoAndStop` statement is being very costly. I'm not sure how to fix this everytime I run the game it just laggs horribly. The user scrolls the characters on the screen and when they hit a mark it activates the `characterBooleanFunction` function. Any ideas? Here is the code:

```
private function characterBooleanFunction():void 
    {
        if (scrollCharacters.mcRandom.hit.hitTestObject(storeScreen.mcMarker) )
       {
           scrollCharacters.mcRandom.gotoAndStop(2);

           //booleans
           bRandom = true;

       }else
       {
           scrollCharacters.mcRandom.gotoAndStop(1);
           bRandom = false;
       }

       if (scrollCharacters.mcChinese.hit.hitTestObject(storeScreen.mcMarker) )
       {
           scrollCharacters.mcChinese.gotoAndStop(2);
           trace("HIT CHINESE");
            //booleans
           bChinese = true;

       }else
       {
           scrollCharacters.mcChinese.gotoAndStop(1);
           bChinese = false;
       }

       if (scrollCharacters.mcPizza.hit.hitTestObject(storeScreen.mcMarker) )
       {
           scrollCharacters.mcPizza.gotoAndStop(2);
           trace("HIT PIZZA");
            //booleans

           bPizza = true;

       }else
       {
           scrollCharacters.mcPizza.gotoAndStop(1);
           bPizza = false;
       }

       if (scrollCharacters.mcBurger.hit.hitTestObject(storeScreen.mcMarker) )
       {
           scrollCharacters.mcBurger.gotoAndStop(2);

            //booleans
           bBurger = true;

       }else
       {
           scrollCharacters.mcBurger.gotoAndStop(1);
           bBurger = false;
       }
```

... so on and so on.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, it seems that you can simplify the code from 30 distinct blocks down to a single loop. Second, call **gotoAndStop** only if the target is at the wrong **currentFrame**. Third, **hitTest** is indeed a resource hungry command, so it's not a bad idea to make a pre-check that could decide not even check two objects for collision because their **x** and **y** coordinates are too far away.

Comment: Thanks @Organis I will definitely use this as a guide to optimizing it. Seems pretty straight forward. Yeah added it all in a for loop but still didnt do anything due to the gotoAndStop statement.

Comment: Also look into switch statements. Doesn't optimize but easier to organize and you can merge multiple cases nicer based on your data.